# How to free memory of element object in java while creating xml using dom?

Tags: java, xml, dom

After appending a child element to its parent while creating an xml document using Java, I want to free memory of the "carname" element object. How can I free the memory without using `System.gc()`?

```
Element carname = doc.createElement("carname");
Attr attrType = doc.createAttibute("type"); 
attrType.setValue("formula one"); 
carname.setAttributeNode(attrType); 
carname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Ferrari 101")); 
supercar.appendChild(carname);
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of sounds like a trick question.

1. supercar will retain a reference to carname, so the object itself won't be garbage collected anyway.
2. carname is such a small object, I wouldn't worry about it.

All of these XML objects will be cleaned up by the gc after all of their references have been released (when your outermost method is done running). Just make sure no one is holding those references and you should be fine.